# Visual studio Express 2013 OR Visual studio Pro 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a business laptop and have these two options mentioned in the title; cost is not a limitation (company licence) and I will be developing simple GUI/console programs.

Currently I'm using `Code::Blocks`, but ran into the situation where I had to use the `WtsApi32` for `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`. I'm struck with the requirement for using `Sal.h`, which comes with MS Visual Studio - I'm thinking of using MS VC++ for this specific application which needs to find out if the current user (multi-monitor setup) has locked his laptop/PC or not.

I need to install either the MS VS Pro **2010** or the MS VS **2013 Express** edition - what are the pros and cons between these two?

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visual Studio Pro 2010 has resource editor and I think also profiler support, but the help system sucks big time (this was the edition where they modernized it, in an associative way) and the compiler, Visual C++, lacks nearly all C++11 features. I used a 3rd party help viewer with VS 2010. However, it was a bit crash prone and generally erratic.

2013 Express Edition lacks a resource editor and GUI for profiler, but has a decent help viewer (they had to give up on the everything-is-web silliness) and more up-to-date compiler which essentially only lacks C++11 `constexpr` in order to be good.

Both are huge downloads.

Comment: VC++ 2010 supports many C++11 features, lambdas, auto, smart pointers, almost complete C++11 library.

Comment: @user515430: your "many" features is an extreme exaggeration, actively misleading the reader. e.g. even the humbe range based for loop is lacking.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf, thanks for your answer and comments (the company has both versions already, but I can install only one). Which is better from a debugging perspective (c++ 11 support is a close second preference)? I guess it is the 2013 Express edition, right?

Comment: I haven't noticed any big changes in the debugging environment from 2010 to 2013, but there may have been some minor changes. However, I've had some problems with setting breakpoints in header files with VIsual Studio for Desktop 2013, and I can't remember any of that with the 2010 editions. So it may be that some bugs were introduced on the way.

Comment: If the "need to install either" isn't the kind of arbitrary micro-management that it sounds like, then you can install BOTH, since the express edition is free. Then you can use the resource editor in VS 2010 Prof, and everything else (especially compiler) in VS 2013 Express. You can download the Express edition for free from Microsoft.